# Why do I get different results running the batch file?

Tags: batch-file, operating-system, windows-installer, wmic

I have batch file:

```
@echo off

set vers=0.0
FOR /F "USEBACKQ" %%A IN (`wmic datafile where name^="C:\\Windows\\System32\\msiexec.exe" get Version`) do (set vers=%%A)

echo %vers% 

@pause
```

Windows XP (SP2):

```
3.0.3790.2180
```

Windows Vista (SP1), Windows XP (x64):

```
ECHO is off.
```

**How to fix that in both situations the  batch file executed correctly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set vers=0.0
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims== usebackq" %%A IN (
        `wmic datafile where name^="C:\\Windows\\System32\\msiexec.exe" get Version /value ^| find "="`
    ) do set "vers=%%A"

    echo %vers% 

    endlocal
pause
```

It just asks wmic to output data in the format `key=value`, filters the output of the wmic command searching only lines with `=` and splits the lines using this character as token delimiter. The first token (the key) is ignored, and second token (the value) is assigned to `vers` variable.